# Is it possible to execute the ssh command without creating a .ssh directory?

Tags: php, ssh

I'm trying to run a command on a remote server via SSH from a PHP script. Here's the snippet:

```
    $ssh_command = "ssh -F keys/config -o UserKnownHostsFile=keys/known_hosts -i keys/deployment_key -p $ssh_port $r
    $git_fetch = "git --git-dir=$remote_path/.git --work-tree=$remote_path fetch 2>&1";
    exec("$ssh_command '$git_fetch' 2>&1", $out);
```

The script works fine if I run it from the command line, because it's running as a user with a regular login shell and their own .ssh directory. When I try to run the script through the Web interface, it fails because SSH can't create its .ssh directory in the Apache user's home directory.

Is it possible to use SSH without the .ssh directory or is there another alternative for running SSH as the Apache user?  I'd prefer not to create a .ssh folder for the Apache user.

Comment: I'm puzzled. Do you have reasons apart from taste? Is it actually worthwhile to compartmentalize SSH within a service running under another user account that takes specific requests from, and gives responses to, your Apache process?

Comment: The main reason I didn't want to use the PHP SSH2 library was that I didn't want to deal with PECL at all. The solution in the accepted answer is a good one, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do it with [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/):

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$key = new Crypt_RSA();
//$key->setPassword('whatever');
$key->loadKey(file_get_contents('privatekey'));

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', $key)) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->read('username@username:~$');
$ssh->write("ls -la\n");
echo $ssh->read('username@username:~$');
?>
```

The only other thing I can imagine people referring to when they say PHP SSH library is the PECL extension.  I'd personally recommend against using that as it's pretty badly written.  The fact that it's hard to install and badly supported aside it requires you provide public and private keys.  phpseclib only requires the private key.  This makes sense because the private keys normally contain the public key embedded within them.  The PECL SSH2 extension requires it be extracted separately, which is silly.

phpseclib also supports a ton more formats than the PECL SSH2 library does.  phpseclib supports the PuTTY key format, XML Signatures keys, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I'm able to get around this restriction with one small issue/side-effect.

Setting the options `UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null` and `StrictHostKeyChecking=no`, you can trick SSH into not actually storing or requiring verification of a host key.

Setting `StrictHostKeyChecking` to no allows the connection to the server without first knowing or verifying its key; and using `/dev/null` for `UserKnownHostsFile` just reads and writes to nothing so no values are ever read of saved.

The caveat was that SSH still tries to create the `.ssh` directory and fails, but the failure results in a warning and it will continue with the connection.  The warning WILL be included in your output (unless you were to suppress warnings).

Here is an example.  Note: For this example I didn't set up any authentication so it will try to use password auth and fail, but since you are using an identity you should be able to connect just fine.

```
<?php
$ssh_command = "ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "
              ."-p 2223 user@host.localdomain";

exec("$ssh_command ls 2>&1", $out);

var_dump($out);

// output when called from browser running as daemon(1)
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(44) "Could not create directory '/usr/sbin/.ssh'."
  [1]=>
  string(110) "Warning: Permanently added '[host.localdomain]:2223,[192.168.88.20]:2223' (RSA) to the list of known hosts."
  [2]=>
  string(36) "Permission denied, please try again."
  [3]=>
  string(36) "Permission denied, please try again."
  [4]=>
  string(82) "Received disconnect from 192.168.88.20: 2: Too many authentication failures for user"
}
```

Your output would most likely only include the first warning about not being able to create the `.ssh` directory, followed by the warning about permanently adding the host to the list of known hosts (`/dev/null`), followed by the output from your command; so you would have to check if the first line was this warning, and shift it from the `$out` array.

Another note: This does open up the possibility of man-in-the-middle attacks or a DNS/IP hack to get you to try to connect to a rogue server.

See this article on [SSH Host Key Protection](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/ssh-host-key-protection) from Symantec.

Comment: You can also manually specify the location of the known_hosts file, which is what I wound up doing. That enables you to avoid the default location without opening up the vulnerability to man-in-the-middle attacks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the first thing that SSH looks for is the user's configuration file. You can use the **-F** flag to specify the location of your own configuration file, which ought to solve the problem, though I'm rushing out to work right now, so I haven't double-checked this. You'll need to specify the location of other things like the identity files, &c., within it, mind. The file will need to have the correct ownership and permissions or SSH will complain.

That said, using an SSH library like SSH2 is a far superior solution to shelling out if at all possible.

Comment: Yeah, it actually still wants to create it even if you tell it to look for the config file elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

No, you need a .ssh in the user's home when using an OpenSSH client. There's no way to avoid this - it's meant to be a security feature since it contains integral settings. Simply keep an empty dummy directory - the client won't write there - but you are required to have adequate user permissions on it.

Comment: Is that also necessary if you use the PHP SSH2 library?

Comment: AFAIK you can use the SSH2 library without any such limitations. In other words: That would be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

DON'T DO THIS. I haven't used PHP in years, but in any modern, general purpose programming language, this would be a huge WTF. I noticed one user commneted about using the PHP SSH2 library... this would be the way to go, IMHO.

Jumping out to shell to execute a command should ONLY occur when you're producing a side-effect where the result is inconsequential. If you're relying on this for anything important, or if the result of the command should modify program state in any way, you either need to find an internal library to handle this, or extend the language to do this properly via the appropriate C libraries. Otherwise, you're setting yourself up for a world of hurt.

Answer (score 0):

You can control where ~/.ssh will land using the HOME environment variable. That way you can be sure it won't be a directory Apache serves.